# Remove mounted drive icon from Ubuntu dock in Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

When you mount a drive or have Google account integration with "Files" application on in Ubuntu 19.10, an icon appears in the dock.
[image]

How do I change this behavior? I don't want any of these icons to show up on the dock.